# React state management solutions vs props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

When using a state management library like Redux or MobX, do i still need to use props?

For example, if a parent is sending a state to the child as a prop, can both parent and child not simply import the Redux/MobX store and call actions on the state through the imported store?

Comment: Redux only works with props, at least if you using correctly through the `connect` method to apply the store state as props on the component. Redux allows you to map the state to props on both parent and child, however, do you really want to have this behavior? You could theoretically let the parent pass the state to the child, depending on how powerfull your child component should actually be. I assume for MobX  that it will be a similar story, but I know very little about it

Answer (score 2):

You should always prefer to React parent-child props passing rather than mapping every component to Redux store because of several reasons:

1. React provides render optimization for parent-child props passing, Redux doesn't. That means every change in Redux store, its mapping components need to re-render causing performance issue. In React, only components that have details changed need to render.
2. You cannot reuse components that mapped with Redux store because they're tightly coupled to each other. Therefore, you cannot fully achieve composable pattern in React. So stay with passing props to components in React way and use Redux mapping in a few key components only.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with any of the points that you have made. Do you have any references on which you are basing these assertions? AFAIK #1. `react-redux` does provide a lot of optimization for rendering. See https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance for more details. Also, in normal parent-child props, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps`to optimize your rendering based on changes in props, the same goes for redux connected components.

Comment: Also, for every change in Redux store, AFAIK only components which subscribe to the state that has changed will be re-rendered, not all components. #2 Components that are connected to the Redux store are smart components and do not depend on the parent component for their props. So they can be reused and re rendered throughout the application without having any kind of coupling with their parents. Components which depend on props from their parents will always need have parents which have the required data to pass as props; which leads to coupling.

Comment: @palsrealm #2 you are wrong about the idea of loose coupling. In a props passing component, it does not care where its props come from as long as the props comply with its interface (PropTypes). Now, if you map the component with a Redux store, it tightly coupled with the store via `mapStateToProps` function. If you change anything on the Redux store, it might break the mapping components. Also, if you want to reuse that same component with another store, we have to change its implementation of `mapStateToProps` as well.

Comment: I agree with what you say, that a component is tightly coupled to its state. If the shape of the state changes the component will be affected. But that should not affect composability of the component and reusability of it in the app, should it?

Comment: @palsrealm Also, making the child component that has no coupling with its parent is nonsense. Of course, they had to have a relationship because we made them parent and child at the first place. The props passing is the mechanism to realize this relationship.

Comment: @palsrealm for #1 As you said, I didn't have concrete proof whether Redux provided render optimization or not. It solely based on my experience with the library. Besides, the React provide enough features to optimize render as you pointed out (shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps) so we should leave the optimization on the React side.

Comment: `making the child component that has no coupling with its parent is nonsense` : There are multiple real-life scenarios where we need a stand alone smart component which is used at multiple places in the application which has no bearing on the parent component. E.g. If SO were written in React,  the component to show the user name with the badges and score would be an example of component that is smart and independent of  its parent.

Comment: I know, it sounds a little bit absurd but making the child component reaching out to grab data from somewhere else instead of its parent is an anti-pattern. That is the reason we should limit the number of smart components to just a few. Also, another Redux replacement - (`graphQL` and `relay`) is doing a good job to comply with this best practice. All the data specs in children components are propagated up the hierarchy and form the final query at the root tto fetch the data and then redistribute the data from top to bottom.

Comment: I do not disagree that making all child components connected is an anti pattern. I do disagree with the reasons you have provided for it being an anti pattern.

Comment: @palsrealm Fair enough, I think it's all come down to personal preference. At an extreme theoretical standpoint, I see it as "rule-breaking" practice therefore declaring it an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Redux or MobX to store your application state, you need to take a decision on which components will be connected (smart) and which will be disconnected (dumb).

The convention is to create smart Containers which are responsible for connecting to the store, updating the state in the store and subscribing to the state changes. These components are the only ones which are aware of the  Redux/MobX store.

The Containers have a number of dumb children which are generally stateless and mainly responsible for the presentational aspects of the app. They are not aware of the existence of the Redux/Mobx store and receive any state changes or actions as props from their parent.

You can get a better idea of the difference between container and presentational components from [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by @DanAbramov, the creator of Redux.